# Can't display all content using Bootstrap JS Collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap JS Collapse to display all content in categories.I have created panels displayed in a column grid but just only first submenu's content was displayed. Please help me fix it.

[UPDATE] I have updated my code but it still incorrect.

---

**Here is my code:**

```
    <div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading "role="tab" id="heading0">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menu0" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="menu0">
                <span class='badge pull-right'><i class='fa fa-plus' ></i></span>                                    Tin tức công ty                                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="menu0" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading0">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>test</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu0" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading0">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>test2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading "role="tab" id="heading1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menu1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="menu1">
                <span class='badge pull-right'><i class='fa fa-plus' ></i></span>                                    Thực phẩm                                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>Thị trường trong nước</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>Thị trường quốc tế</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>Bánh Kẹo</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>Đồ uống</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>test3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end.collapse -->
```

[Here is result failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhRtG.png)

Comment: Look at the example in Bootstrap documentation, try to understand it and neaten your code :) http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: @makshh: I tried but i didn't understand why's wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading " role="tab" id="heading0">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menu0" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="menu0">
                <span class='badge pull-right'><i class='fa fa-plus' ></i></span>                                    Tin tức công ty                                </a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="menu0" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading0">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading " role="tab" id="heading1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menu1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="menu1">
                <span class='badge pull-right'><i class='fa fa-plus' ></i></span>                                    Thực phẩm                                </a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li>Thị trường trong nước</li>
          <li>Thị trường quốc tế</li>
          <li>Bánh Kẹo</li>
          <li>test3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/zhroubfc/)